# VS Code disables highlighting occurrences but also disables highlighting matching tags

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, highlight

I want to disable highlighting occurrences but preserve highlighting matching tags. At the moment when I set occurrencesHighlight: false it stops highlighting occurrences but at the same time stops highlighting opening and closing tags.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Language specific settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings)

```json
"editor.occurrencesHighlight": false,
"[html]": {
    "editor.occurrencesHighlight": true
}
```